# onMouseMove + onMouseDown to call function

Tags: javascript, onclick, substitution, onmousedown, onmousemove

I have a real problem over here. I want a function to get called only when an object is clicked and when when the mouse is moved over the object. Here is an example (ignore the weird syntax) to get your understanding:

```
<div onMouseMove+onMouseDown="function()" ... ></div>
```

I was thinking of a way to solve this. What if I make a `onMouseDown` that trigger a function that will change the name of my `onMouseMove` - function, and use a "filler" or a "substitute" function? Let me explain:

```
<div id="object" onMouseMove="substituteFiller()" onMouseDown="nameChanger()" ... ></div>
<script>
    function nameChanger(){
        document.getElementById("object").onMouseMove = "theRealFunction()"; 
    }
</script>
<script>
    function theRealFunction() ...
```

When I move the mouse over the object nothing will happen, because the function `substituteFiller()` won't work. But, when the mouse has clicked on the object the `onMouseMove`- function will be the correct one, `theRealFunction()`, and `theRealFunction()` will now get called when the mouse moves.

This way I could activate/call `theRealFunction()` only when the object is clicked and when the mouse moved. However, it does not work.

To be clear: how can I change the name of the function that is being called? How can I make a function to be called only when an object is clicked and mouse moved?

Best regards, hope you understood! If not, comment I guess!

Comment: Do you mean that the user clicks and the action happens only after they move the mouse?

Comment: Yes, exactly (move over/click the specific object)! Not when the user click, and not when the user only moves over, but when the user clicks (holds down, onMouseDown) and move the mouse. Much like a "dragging" motion! :)

Comment: If you found an answer helpful, you may want to mark it as accepted. Don't hesitate to ask for further clarifications in the comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, all you need to do is separately register 3 event handlers:

1. *mouse down*
2. *mouse up*
3. *mouse move*

You will have a boolean flag toggled to true and false on *mouse down* and *up* respectively. Then, on the *mouse move* handler, you need to check if the flag is true, which would mean the mouse button is down. Finally, we check to see if the cursor has actually moved from its initial position.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01ezmop1/).

```
var example = document.getElementById("example");
var position = {
  X: 0,
  Y: 0
};

example.onmousedown = function (down) {
  downFlag = true;
  // Record click position
  position.X = down.clientX;
  position.Y = down.clientY;
};

example.onmouseup = function (up) {
  downFlag = false;
};

example.onmousemove = function (move) {
  if (downFlag) {
    if (position.X !== move.clientX || position.Y !== move.clientY) {
      // Do stuff here
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Wow man, legendary! So does this mean that one can't change which function that will get called from for example `onMouseMove`, by using the `document.getElementById("...").onMouseMove = function ();` - way? Thank you very much again!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can call any function you want, with the `event` as an argument. Alternatively, you can use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Its a part from one of my web page..Check It out.May this will help you..

```
<div id="Log_frm">
<fieldset id="fld_1">
    <!--<legend>Log In</legend>-->        
    <div id="log_l" onmouseover="dv_in();" onmouseout="dv_out();" style="background-color:#0C93D4;font-size: 15px;height: 30px;padding: 7px 32px 0px 32px;font-weight:bold; float: left;-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;">
        <a  href="#" onclick="">Log In</a>
    </div>
    <div id="log_r" onmouseover="dv_out();" onmouseout="dv_in();"style="background-color: #0C93D4;font-size: 15px;font-weight:bold; float: right;height: 30px;padding: 7px 14px 0px 12px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;">
        <a  href="#">Need Any Help</a>
    </div >   
    </fieldset>
</div>

<style>
#Log_frm {
    width: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: right;
    right: 0px;
}

#Log_frm a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function dv_in() {  
            log_l.style.backgroundColor="#06C"; 
            log_r.style.backgroundColor="#0C93D4"; 
        }
        function dv_out() {  
            log_l.style.backgroundColor="#0C93D4"; 
            log_r.style.backgroundColor="#06C";
        }


</script>
```

Regds..